# Why this code is not working as Deadlock?

Tags: multithreading, deadlock, runnable, synchronized

```
class A {

  synchronized void bar(B b) {

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("Entered In A "+t);

    try{
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
    System.out.println("A trying to enter B");
    b.last();
  }

  synchronized void last() {

      System.out.println("Inside A last");

 }
}


class B {

   synchronized void bar(A a) {

    Thread t = Thread.currentThread();
    System.out.println("Entered In B "+t);
    try{
      Thread.sleep(1000);
    }
    catch(Exception e) {
    }
     System.out.println("B trying to enter A");
     a.last();
  }

  synchronized void last() {

    System.out.println("Inside B last");

  }
}

class Main {

  public static void main(String[] args) {

      A a = new A();
      B b = new B();
      // Thread t1 = new Thread(){
      //   public void run() {
      //     a.bar(b);
      //   }
      // };
      Thread t2 = new Thread() {
        public void run() {
          b.bar(a);
        }
      };
      System.out.println("Initialization :");
     // t1.start();
      a.bar(b);
      t2.start();

  }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code doesn't start the `t2` thread until *after* the `a.bar(b)` call has returned. It never tries to call both `bar()` methods concurrently.

Try switching those last two lines: Call `t2.start()` first, and *then* call `a.bar(b)`.

---

If that doesn't work, then maybe try:

```
t2.start();
try { sleep(100); } catch {...}
a.bar(b);
```

The short `sleep()` call in the main thread will give the `t2` thread more time to start up and actually enter the `b.bar(a)` call.

Comment: Switching the two lines worked. So i can conclude that the main thread is already started so it reaches bar() first and then the second thread starts, so at no point both the thread are calling bar concurrently.